# DataFrame.Apply() ignoring the first column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Problem**

I have a function `MovingAverage` that calculates the moving average of a series. Now I am trying to apply this function to columns of a DataFrame using `apply()`. It seems to be working fine for all columns except the first column. I am unable to debug as why `apply()` is ignoring first column of DataFrame.

**Data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Action':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Adventure':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Comedy':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Fantasy':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Drama':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10)})
```

**Code**

```
# function: MovingAverage()
def MovingAverage(xSeries, MA_Limit = 1):
    MA_Series = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(xSeries), dtype=float))
    for i in range(MA_Limit, len(xSeries)):
        MA_Series[i] = np.mean(xSeries[i-MA_Limit:i])

    j = MA_Limit
    while j > 0:
        MA_Series[j-1] = np.mean(xSeries[0:j])
        j = j-1

    return MA_Series
```

Here is the actual function call,

```
df.apply(MovingAverage, axis=1, MA_Limit=5)
```

**Current Output**

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQs7A.png)

**Expected Output**

Moving average filter applied to each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First column is not changed, because mean of scalar is same value.

It looks like need [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `axis=1` for processes rows:

```
np.random.seed(456)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Action':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Adventure':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Comedy':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Fantasy':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10),
                   'Drama':np.random.randint(0, 11, 10)})
print (df1)
   Action  Adventure  Comedy  Fantasy  Drama
0       5          5       0        3     10
1       9          2       9        3      5
2      10          4      10        5      1
3      10          2       8       10      6
4       4          2       2        6      1
5       5          8       3        6      5
6       7          4       6        3     10
7       1          8       7        8      9
8       8          5       0        9      1
9       3          6       0        6      4

#also first column is noct changed
df2 = df1.rolling(3, min_periods=1, axis=1).mean()
print (df2)
   Action  Adventure    Comedy   Fantasy     Drama
0     5.0        5.0  3.333333  2.666667  4.333333
1     9.0        5.5  6.666667  4.666667  5.666667
2    10.0        7.0  8.000000  6.333333  5.333333
3    10.0        6.0  6.666667  6.666667  8.000000
4     4.0        3.0  2.666667  3.333333  3.000000
5     5.0        6.5  5.333333  5.666667  4.666667
6     7.0        5.5  5.666667  4.333333  6.333333
7     1.0        4.5  5.333333  7.666667  8.000000
8     8.0        6.5  4.333333  4.666667  3.333333
9     3.0        4.5  3.000000  4.000000  3.333333
```

---

```
#first row is not changed, because rolling mean per columns (default axis=0)
df3 = df1.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
print (df3)
     Action  Adventure    Comedy   Fantasy      Drama
0  5.000000   5.000000  0.000000  3.000000  10.000000
1  7.000000   3.500000  4.500000  3.000000   7.500000
2  8.000000   3.666667  6.333333  3.666667   5.333333
3  9.666667   2.666667  9.000000  6.000000   4.000000
4  8.000000   2.666667  6.666667  7.000000   2.666667
5  6.333333   4.000000  4.333333  7.333333   4.000000
6  5.333333   4.666667  3.666667  5.000000   5.333333
7  4.333333   6.666667  5.333333  5.666667   8.000000
8  5.333333   5.666667  4.333333  6.666667   6.666667
9  4.000000   6.333333  2.333333  7.666667   4.666667
```

Comment: Got the problem in my code from your solution. Thanks! 

Actually, what I wanted was to apply the filter row-wise on all columns.... so I mixed up the jargon.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply moving average, just using the `rolling()` function. For windows size 2,

```
df1.rolling(window=[![enter image description here][1]][1]2).mean()
```